# Android's inputType="textEmailAddress" changes height

Tags: android, email, layout, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I already designed my Username EditText with height, I tried to copy the same properties to my Email EditText and when I changed the InputType to "textEmailAddress", my custom height property was ignored.
Here is my email EditText code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/Alpha_White"
        android:ems="10"
        android:height="37dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:maxLength="22"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:width="230dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your custom height in the android:layout_height attribute